# 2 Services Communicating

Tags: android, service, ipc

I have a service that starts another remote service. when the second service have started, it binds to the first service using IPC, and all works great.

My question is, i would like the first service to be able to talk to the second service as well (right now, only the other way around is implemented). can i somehow do it with the same Binder? or should i bind the first service to the second one? 
maybe there's a way to make two services talk on the same connection somehow?

All help would be appreciated.

Vlad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the first `Service` to call methods on the second `Service`, then you'll need to get a `Binder` from the second `Service`. If you just want to communicate, you could use `Broadcasts` and set up a `Receiver` in the first `Service`.

Comment: so basicly there's no problem having 2 services that each holds a Binder of the other one?

Comment: thanks. i have some problems with that.. but i guess i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think that two way communication using the same binder is impossible for services. I have tried a lot, and the problem I found, using the parlance of your own example is that IBinder interfaces retrieved from the second service are always null.
I mean, the first service would have bind to the second in order to obtain a valid IBinder to talk to  the second service. The limitation is that when the second service calls the first, it cannot pass interfaces to the first service so callbacks(from first to second) can take place.
A new independent IBinder connection to the second service needs to be established, instead. Hope somebody can help us with this one.

Alberto.

Comment: you're probably right. fortunately, i don't need this feature anymore. but it seems kinda funny that the communication is one-sided.. there are many uses for two sided communication, but with two different Ibinders, the code becomes messy and unnecessarily long..